# Unable to start Bridge server - Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bridge

I have been able to get bridge up and running on my local macbook, however I run into problems when trying to set it up on my ubuntu box hosted on Linode.

I installed rabbitmq using apt-get install rabbitmq-server. Then I followed the server installation guide on the website. When I try to run the commant ~/.bridge/setup start I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@li532-27:~/.bridge# 
 =====
 ===== LOGGING STARTED Sat Sep 29 18:32:37 UTC 2012
 =====
 Exec: /root/.bridge/bridge-server/erts-5.8.5/bin/erlexec -boot /root/.bridge/bridge- server/releases/5/server -mode embedded -config /root/.bridge/bridge-server/etc/app.config -args_file /root/.bridge/bridge-server/etc/vm.args -- console
 Root: /root/.bridge/bridge-server
```

And nothing happens after. Not sure what I am doing wrong because it worked on my local macbook machine.

Any ideas?